# Cannot get wireless to work on my HP Netbook with Ubuntu Netbook Remix

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, ubuntu-netbook-remix

I have installed Ubuntu Netbook remix 9.x on my HP netbook. But wireless is not working properly. I went to Network Connections and it shows my wireless connection. But under "Last Used" column, it says never. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the ubuntu netbook remix and installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and wireless is working now